# Doing a MINUS on 2 different databases?

Tags: database, postgresql, db2, netezza

Is it possible to do a MINUS on 2 different databases

```
DB-A is on Postgres 
DB-B is on DB2 or Netezza
```

Taking the assumptions that both the tables in the DB-A and DB-B have the same columns and the same column names

Can I do a query like the following?

```
SELECT * 
FROM <HOSTNAME>.DB-A

MINUS

SELECT * 
FROM <HOSTNAME>.DB-B
```

Or is there some other method to do this comparison, without copying the entire data of one DB Table to the other DB?

Comment: May be (I don't see anything for those specific databases), lookup foreign data wrappers  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers

Comment: ...which will still, under the hood, result in "copying the entire data of one table to the other database".

Comment: @mustaccio so is it possible to do this or not? If one DB is on the Cloud (accessed via a URL like hotname) and the other is on a physical machine to which I have a ODBC/JDBC connection?